# Angular - push object to list of objects

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting some list of data from database, with angular I'm adding it to scope. 
So on $scope I have list of objects

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Where each looks like:

```
0: "1"
1: "This is my first task"
2: "1"
3: "1"
$$hashKey: "object:3"
active: "1"
id: "1"
priority: "1"
text: "This is my first task"
```

I basicly try to add new OBJECT to it, with something like:

```
$scope.tasks.push($scope.newTask);
```

But this add just string / array not an object,
I already tryed to add multiple other way to add object like

```
$scope.tasks.push("text": $scope.newTask);
```

But I can't make it work, please may I ask you for help to lead on correct way?

Comment: Please do `console.log($scope.newTask);` and show us the result.

Comment: Hey @taxicala it return value from input, so if I write to <input> something like THIS IS IT, it return this as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the value of an input, it will be a string always, you can push an object as follows:

```
$scope.tasks.push({"text": $scope.newTask});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json.stingify  and pass the result to the push

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if I understand that correctly but If I do:
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.newTask);
        $scope.tasks.push(jsonString);
result is same, there is a string added instead of object

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to add new objects into array of objects, first you need to access array and then properties of an objcet that are inside it, for example:

```
 $scope.phonebook = [
       {
           name: 'Johan',
           phone: '622345871',
           email: 'johan@yahoo.com'
       }
 ];

 $scope.addPerson = function(){    // triger function when submit button is called

       // check against empty fields
       if ( $scope.name != '' ) {  
          // values from input fields
          $scope.phonebook.push({
              name: $scope.name,
              phone: $scope.phone,
              email: $scope.email
          });
          // clear input fields after submission
          $scope.name = '';
          $scope.phone = '';
          $scope.email = '';
      }
  }
```

hope this will be helpfull, good luck!